# Validating Email Address,Phone,ID Number using javascript in nintex forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, sharepoint

I have a nintex forms that I am building in my sharepoint 2013 environment, now I am not familiar with JavaScript's and have not used javaScripts before!

I want to validate email address, cellphone/telephone number and ID number while the customer is still filling in the form, I believe that can be done with javascripts code inside the nintex form

I tried posting a question in the nintex community but haven't got any reply since yesterday

Would appreciate any ideas and solution on how would I go about doing that!

Comment: Please use https://community.nintex.com/community/support for such questions

Comment: it's a commercial product, Nintex has a community for such cases https://community.nintex.com/community/support

Comment: ok thanks, I will just wait as I already posted the question yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the nintex form-designer you can use Regex. In the field-properties (double click textbox) you are able define the validation (range, Regex...).

example: regex Email: `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$`

Comment: hi there, thanks for your answer I added the code but when I click save with an email example : example@email.co.za or example@gmail.com it still says invalid email but when I remove the email and save it continue

Comment: there is another field/property :> Requiered Field Message... Add e errormessage and it will check automaticly

Comment: Yes I did add the error message which is the one am getting "invalid email address" when I enter above mentioned emails

Comment: strange.. i have this in my forms and it works (Sharepoint 2013 SP1/Nintex Forms 2013) maybe a bug!? (w had a lot of problems with Nintex validation) 1111 is not a number....

Comment: ok I will try creating a new test list to see if it does the same thing on it.. thanks for you help

Comment: i hope it will help... else... -> Support-Ticket... but i know, the support from nintex is realy bad :(

Comment: hi there,it worked I guess the something wrong with my form,but I created a new list and just a simple form and it worked fine,thanks for your help once again

Comment: Cool. Your welcome. and thanks.. if i same have the problem next time.. i will try with recreate :)

Answer (score 0):

Nintex Email Validation
Control Settings - Single Line Textbox --> Validation -->
Use a regular expression : Yes
Regular Expression : .+@.+(.).+
Regular expression error message  : Enter a valid email address

Code
.+@.+(.).+